# Having trouble getting Jquery .closest() working?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble getting Jquery `.closest()` to work.

Here's my code, it's simple and I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work:

**Jquery**

```
show:function(a,fx){
        $('.more-content').hide();

        $(a).toggle(function() {
                t = $(this).closest(".more-content")
                if (fx.match('show')) {
                    t.show()
                };
                if (fx.match('slide')) {
                    t.slideDown()
                };
                if (fx.match('fade')) {
                    t.fadeIn()
                };
                $(this).html('Less')
            }, function() {
                if (fx.match('show')) {
                    t.hide()
                };
                if (fx.match('slide')) {
                    t.slideUp()
                };
                if (fx.match('fade')) {
                    t.fadeOut()
                };
                $(this).html('More')
            });
        }
```

**HTML**

```
    <p><strong class="goal">The Goal</strong><br />
    To support those who are NEET <span class="more-content">We do this by providing education or training to enable said people to be...</span>
    <span class="more">More</span>

    <br /><br />
    To build community cohesion in the local area. <span class="more-content">This will lead to a community where people have the opportunity...</span> 
    <span class="more">More</span>
    </p>
```

Confused, so any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: make sure you end your jQuery statements with `;`

Comment: and please show your markup; we can't verify your selectors/traversal without seeing the markup!

Comment: More than likely `.more-content` is not an ancestor of the anchor tag, since it would have to be visible if it was for the anchor tag to be visible. `.closest` is only for selecting ancestors, not siblings. Please read the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @Mathletics I've added the HTML to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `a` variable being passed into the `show` method is the `.more` elements then you want to use select a sibling element, not an ancestor element.

```
var t = $(this).prev(".more-content");
```

Also you are creating a global variable (`t`) to save the current element for your toggle functions but this is not a good way to do that. Just select the proper `t` element in both functions:

var fx = 'slide';

```
$(a).toggle(function() {
    var t = $(this).prev(".more-content");

    if (fx.match('show')) {
        console.log('1');
        t.show();
    };
    if (fx.match('slide')) {
        console.log('2');
        t.slideDown();
    };
    if (fx.match('fade')) {
        console.log('3');
        t.fadeIn();
    };
    $(this).html('Less')
}, function() {
    var t = $(this).prev(".more-content");
    if (fx.match('show')) {
        t.hide()
    };
    if (fx.match('slide')) {
        t.slideUp()
    };
    if (fx.match('fade')) {
        t.fadeOut()
    };
    $(this).html('More')
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/At3bL/1/

Comment: I need to target the closest sibling to whatever the `$(a)` is

Comment: I've already tried `.prev()` but it causes conflict if both `.more-content` are open at the same time

Comment: @Nasir `.more-content` are the previous-adjacent-siblings of the `.more` elements, so using `.prev('.more-content')` will work fine. Check-out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/At3bL/1/

Comment: @Nasir My code works, the problem you had is that you were setting the `t` variable as a global so it was being confused in the different event handlers. Make sure to use `var t = ...` in both functions and they will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks a trillion, that worked... I just needed to add the `var t...` to the other part of the toggle fn